# How can I free someone who is imprisoned after having drawn the Donjon card from the Deck of Many Things?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Disclaimer: I have no experience on using the Deck of Many Things, either as a DM or player.

The description of the Donjon card from the [Deck of Many Things](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things) says:

> You disappear and become entombed in a state of suspended animation in an extradimensional sphere. Everything you were wearing and carrying stays behind in the space you occupied when you disappeared. **You remain imprisoned until you are found and removed from the sphere.** You can't be located by any Divination magic, but a *wish* spell can reveal the location of your prison. You draw no more cards.

The description is vague and does not exactly tells what to do to rescue the victim, except "you must be found and removed from the sphere". It does not say how to find the victim, how to remove them from the sphere, and other limitations.

For example, does the prison lie on a specific plane, which can be accessed by the *plane shift* spell? How can I break/remove someone from the sphere? Is it simply by going there and grabbing them outside their original position?

**How does freeing a victim from Donjon work?**

Answer (score 4):

## A combination of Wish and planar movement

First you need to find the person. The spell gives one example of how this is done (a *wish* spell) though it does not exclude other methods excepts the use of divination magic.

The second part is getting the person out of said sphere. As he/she is in an extra dimensional sphere you would need some kind of interdimensional movement like *plane shift*. As you know where this person is you should be able to get exactly to his location.

Comment: The spell text states that it can be done with a wish spell, not that a wish spell is the only thing that can locate the victim. You can't use divination magic but alternate methods (a quest, most likely, decided by the GM) could locate the victim.